# How to encrypt a btrfs subvolume?

Tags: encryption, btrfs, disk-encryption

I'm looking for information about encryption with btrfs. I have experience with full-disk (LVM actually) encryption, so this time I only need to look at some btrfs specific questions.

I have found [this article on archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Btrfs_subvolumes_with_swap), and find this method is just the same as the previous encryption way I used (some time ago), except for the fact that they are using btrfs subvolumes instead of LVM.

For me, I don't want / need a full-partition encryption as the `home` subvolume(s) is(are) the only place where I'd like to encrypt. (Actually there are more subvolumes under `home`, but that's another question.)
However, through my search, I don't find any information about how to encrypt a btrfs subvolume only. The only most relevant thing I find is [this mail](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-btrfs@vger.kernel.org/msg51159.html) from the btrfs mailing list, which is an experimental patch which provides transparent(?) encryption of btrfs (subvolume).
I also couldn't think out of my mind what method can be used to encrypt a subvolume only.

So, my main question is:

Is it possible to encrypt a btrfs **subvolume** only (no need to be "transparent encryption")? If yes, how?

Side note: Creating an encrypted block (file) and mount it on the "subvolume" is not an acceptable method since it is not a "subvolume" at all.

Comment: AFAIK, btrfs doesn't support subvolume encryption..at least it didn't last time I looked closely at btrfs a few years ago.  zfsonlinux added it [last year](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/commit/b52563034230b35f0562b6f40ad1a00f02bd9a05) ("datasets" are the ZFS equivalent to "subvolumes").

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to encrypt a btrfs **subvolume** only
> (no need to be "transparent encryption")?

No, BTRFS does not currently have built-in support for encryption. 
Today, to encrypt a filesystem (not just a sub-volume) you'd need DM-Crypt/LUKS. 
See the [Btrfs Wiki FAQ](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_Btrfs_support_encryption.3F).

Comment: Were I correct, BTRFS's (supposed) encryption support is for transparent encryption. Is there no way to perform manual encryption on subvolumes?

Comment: The encryption support you mentioned is experimental and as far as I know is not included in mainline. I don't know how well maintained those patches are. Today, encryption for BTRFS is done at the block device level using DM-Crypt/LUKS, which encompasses the entire filesystem; hence there's no sub-volume encryption.

Comment: Having said that, eCryptFS effectively creates an encrypted layer on top of any filesystem. See http://ecryptfs.org/